# Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 - 2)$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove or disprove that $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 - 2)$ is a field.

I am pretty sure it is not a field because if you consider $F = \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x]$ where $F$ is a field, then char $F = 0$.

Not sure how to write a proof for this though.

Comment: An intuitive reason is that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has Krull dimension $2$, and so the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-2)$ has dimension at least $1$, while fields have dimension $0$.

Comment: @SteveD Just to point out, it has dimension exactly one. It's an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, and thus preserves dimensions. In fact, it's a Dedekind domain since it's actually $\mathcal{O}_K$ for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Right, but I was merely pointing out the fact that quotienting by a principal ideal can't lower the dimension too much.  It could be worse, as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(4)$ shows.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;x^3-2\in\Bbb F_7[x]\;\;\text{is irreducible}\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\text{As ideals in}\;\Bbb Z[x]\;\;,\;\;\langle\;x^3-2\;\rangle \lneqq\langle\;x^3-2\,,\,7\;\rangle\end{align*}$$

You may want to try to prove the general theorem: an ideal in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is maximal iff it is of the form $\;\langle f(x),p\rangle\;$ , with $\;p\;$ a prime and $\;f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ such that $\;f(x)\pmod p\;$ irreducible in $\;\Bbb Z_p[x]\;$ .

Personally for me, the above is one of the most stunning and beautiful facts in basic abstract algebra.

Comment: Your answer is exactly the same as mine :D

Comment: Yup. It took me some few seconds to come up with the smallest prime for which the given polynomial is irreducible modulo that prime.

Comment: In fact, checking it I think you posted your answer some 15 second (!) before I did...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think char 0 matters? If you can answer that question, that would give a lead to coming up with a proof.

It does turn out to be true that every quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has nonzero characteristic, so there is surely a proof along these lines.  It would require two parts: showing that $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3-2)$ is actually characteristic 0 (under the assumption it is a field), and showing that this is a contradiction.

I don't know what particular things you know, so I'm not really sure how to suggest going about the problem along these lines.

The simplest is probably, IMO, inspired by the fact a char 0 field must contain $\mathbb{Q}$: find some integer $n$ for which you can easily prove that $n$ is both nonzero and noninvertible in $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 - 2)$.

Comment: In fact, every finitely generated field is finite. So, you could just note that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-2)$ is not finite :)

Comment: Or you could find some prime number $p$ such that $(p,x^3-2)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @JSchlather Or just use the fact that $(2,x^3-2)\supsetneq (x^3-2)$ :)

Comment: Lots of good ways to approach the problem. But I'm hoping there's one that reinforces whatever intuition the OP has on the problem! :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see your quotient is not a field is to note there is some maximal ideal containing $x^3 - 2$. One such maximal ideal is $(7,x^3 - 2)$. To see this is maximal, it is enough to observe that $x^3 - 2$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}/7\Bbb{Z}[x]$. For a cubic, this amounts to showing there are no roots, and we see that $1^3 - 2 \neq 0, 2^3 - 2\neq 0$, $3^3 - 2 = 6 \neq 0$, $4^3 - 2 = 62 \neq 0$, $5^3 -2 = 4 \neq 0$, $6^3 - 2 = 4 \neq 0$ mod $7$.

Comment: You don't even have to do this. You just have to note that there is SOME ideal properly containing $(x^3-2)$--it needn't be maximal. $(2,x^3-2)$ contains $(x^3-2)$, but certainly $2\notin (x^3-2)$.

Comment: Checking that $(7,x^3-2)$ is maximal is beside the point.  The important things to check are a) that $(7,x^3-2)$ is a *proper* ideal and b) that $(7,x^3-2)$ is not the same as $(x^3-2)$.

Comment: @WillO If you know the ideal is maximal then that's enough to show it's proper by definition of a maximal ideal. And point (b) is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of nice ideas. Its amazing how many ways one can approach a problem. A good way for me to see this problem is most likely through a contradiction. I appreciate everyone's help. Now I am going to attempt a proof by contradiction and let me know how this sounds. This is what I have obtained:

Suppose $F = \mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

char $f = 0 \Rightarrow 2$ should be an invertible modulus $(x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then we have that $(d(x) + (x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x])(2 + (x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x]) = 1 + (x^3 - 2)\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Assume that deg $d(x) \leq 2$.

Hmm how should I conclude this then?